# its posible implement oAuth 2.0 with OWIN on AWS lambda NetCore ? AWS lambda Support OWIN?

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, aws-lambda, serverless

I have problem with compilation with aws lambda based on Net Core  on file:
LambdaEntryPoint.cs and LocalEntryPoint.cs

Because these work with 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
but i Need work with Owin

i try implement my App with owin and i try use IAppBuilder 
[StartUp Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdSOR.png)

[AuthConfiguration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AV447.png)

[LambdaEntryPoint.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvdMe.png)

[LocalEntryPoint.css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0i21A.png)

Comment: Please provide some steps that you followed  with details (and possible links) and describe the actual traceback of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

API gateway / OAuth works in terms of an authoriser firing when an access token is received for the first time. The authorizer then has to write a policy document that is forwarded to your lambdas. Not sure .net stack will help with this. Here is an old write up of mine that I'm in the process of updating: https://authguidance.com/2018/12/23/cloud-api-key-technical-points/